# Is this hierarchy of manifolds correct?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds, differential-topology

> **Question:** a Hausdorff *differentiable* manifold (locally Euclidean space): $$ \text{is metrizable} \iff \text{is paracompact} \iff \text{admits a Riemannian metric} \,?$$
>
> Does one also have for a locally Euclidean Hausdorff space (not necessarily differentiable): $$\text{second countable} \iff \text{metrizable with countably many connected components}? $$
>
> Thus second countability is *strictly* stronger for such spaces than metrizability/paracompactness/existence of a Riemannian metric?

([According to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/181270/equivalent-form-of-definition-of-manifolds), it seems they are all equivalent when connectedness is assumed, and according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842750/existence-of-a-universal-cover-of-a-manifold) even equivalent to the existence of a universal cover when connected.)

**Attempt:** By the [Smirnov metrization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrization_theorem#Metrization_theorems), a locally metrizable space (e.g. locally Euclidean spaces) are metrizable if and only if they are Hausdorff and paracompact.

According to Wikipedia, [Riemannian manifolds are metrizable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Riemannian_manifolds_as_metric_spaces_2).

(Is this only true for connected Riemannian manifolds, or can we use the trick where we make the metric less than 1 on each connected component and 1 for distances between points in different components? Or perhaps only when there are at most countably many components?)

Finally, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold#Existence_of_a_metric), any ***differentiable*** paracompact manifold admits a Riemannian metric (I'm not sure if the differentiable hypothesis is necessary -- [this question seems related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1385559/is-every-topological-manifold-completely-metrizable)).

Thus (at least for *connected*, differentiable Hausdorff manifolds) "admits Riemannian metric" $\implies$ "metrizable" $\implies$ paracompact $\implies$ "admits Riemannian metric".

**Context:** This question is motivated by how the definition of manifold used by Spivak in *Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* ([see here for a related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434798/difference-between-two-definitions-of-manifold)) is different from the one used by Lee in *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (where second countability is required). In particular, I had thought that the definition my professor was using (Hausdorff, metrizable, locally Euclidean) was equivalent to Lee's, until Spivak started mentioning a bunch of counterexamples which I recognized as not being second countable. Although I don't remember if my professor specified countably many components, which would rule out most of Spivak's counterexamples consisting of uncountable spaces with the discrete topology and metric.

Comment: Seems correct to me, if it helps you (and you don't know it already) Uryshon's Metrization theorem, insures that any manifold is metrizable (where by manifold I mean a second-countable, Hausdorff with a smooth atlas).

Comment: @mayer_vietoris I don't think I knew the application of Urysohn's metrization theorem here, so this definitely helps me -- I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the answer to many of these questions can be found on p.459, Appendix A, of Spivak's *Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry*, 3rd edition 1999.

Specifically, the Theorem appaears to address my confusion regarding how the cardinality of the number of components of a manifold plays into these properties/definitions.

Note that this seems to hold even for topological manifolds, i.e. not necessarily smooth ones.

> **Theorem** The following properties are equivalent for any manifold $M$:
>
> (a) Each component of $M$ is $\sigma$-compact.
> (b) Each component of $M$ is second countable (has a countable base for the topology).
> (c) $M$ is metrizable.
> (d) $M$ is paracompact.
>
> (In particular, a compact manifold is metrizable.)